# ElasticSearch bag-of-words field matching

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5

there is a very simple thing I have been trying to do with ES, and only managed via a workaround:
given a query and a document field, match all the query's terms with all the field's terms.
In other words :

1. the query's terms are a subset of the field's
2. the field's terms are a subset of the query's

Requirement 1) is satisfied by using an `and` operator in a match query. But I have not been able to find a way for 2).

They only way I managed to achieve this so far is by leveraging `highlight` and requiring that all of the string is highlighted (in my application logic)

Is there another way?

Example:

```
PUT bananas/banana/1
{ "name" : "banana"}

PUT bananas/banana/2
{ "name" : "ripe banana"}


PUT bananas/banana/3
{ "name" : "not so ripe banana"}

GET bananas/_search
{
  "query" : {
    "match": { "_all": { "query": "ripe banana", "operator": "and" } }
  },
  "highlight" : {
    "fields" : { "*" : { } },
    "require_field_match": false
  }
}

# Result (hits only):

  "hits" : {
    "hits" : [
      {
        "_index" : "bananas",
        "_type" : "banana",
        "_id" : "3",
        "_score" : 0.5753642,
        "_source" : {
          "name" : "not so ripe banana"
        },
        "highlight" : {
          "name" : [
            "not so <em>ripe</em> <em>banana</em>"
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "bananas",
        "_type" : "banana",
        "_id" : "2",
        "_score" : 0.51623213,
        "_source" : {
          "name" : "ripe banana"
        },
        "highlight" : {
          "name" : [
            "<em>ripe</em> <em>banana</em>"
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  }
```

So in this case I would like to exclude the result for "not so ripe bananas" (it even returns first for some reason!).
My workaround is examining the `highlight` part of the response to see if there is something non-highlighted

Comment: Why not make an inner field for name (eg. name.normalized) and make it type keyword and attach a normalizer to it for lowercasing. Then use a term filter on this new field as part of you query (wrap them in a bool). If you want I can work out an example, if the explanation is too vague :)

Comment: Firs of all, thanks a lot for mentioning the the [normalizers](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-normalizers.html), I did not know about them.

Now  with regards to the problem, if I understand you answer correctly, I think it stills solves condition 1: the query's terms are a subset of the field's.
How would it make sure that the field had no **extra** fields than the ones int the query ? Am I missing something?

Another detail is you would need to tokenize the query in the app logic, which could return different terms than ES. But that's solvable

Comment: Actually I'm wrong. Since the resulting field is `keyword`, you can do exact matching to it.
So the (only) problems with that solution:
 1) it's sensitive to term order, 2) relies on app tokenization, 3) can't account for stopwords ([stop token filters](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-stop-tokenfilter.html))